# Can't send mail with Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, sendmail, google-cloud-functions, mail-server

I'm trying to send an email from a Cloud Function using the [sendmail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sendmail) package.
It works when I host my "send function" locally. And I can deploy the function without problems to my Firebase project.

In the log at Firebase I can see this message:

```
Error: queryMx ESERVFAIL hotmail.com
at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:219:19)
```

I'm neither familiar with sending emails from servers or Cloud Functions for Firebase. My question is why I got this error and how I can make it work?

Here is an excerpt from my function:

```
sendmail({
        from: body.name + ' ' + '<' + body.email + '>',
        to: 'soerensmed@hotmail.com',
        subject: 'Henvendelse via kontaktformular',
        html: html,
    }, function (err, reply) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err && err.stack);
            response.status(500).end()
        }
        else {
            console.log(reply)
            response.status(200).end()
        }
    });
```

I'm developing a website where people can contact me through a contact form. The goal is to receive an email with the message... If this approach isn't possible I'm open for suggestions on how I can set this contact-email-thing up using Angular and Firebase.

Comment: While I'm not sure why this isn't working, you can check out this sample from the Cloud Functions for Firebase samples on GitHub: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/email-confirmation. It shows you how to send an email using Nodemailer.

Comment: Thank you, Jen. I got it work using a https://www.mailgun.com/ account... I'm still interested in knowing if it is possible to send emails directly from a Cloud Function just like I tried.

Comment: I'll take a look at Nodemailer

Answer (score 0):

It will not work with cloud function with free spark account. You should upgrade as it is clearly defined in pricing section in network box. https://firebase.google.com/pricing/